# Update android compose ScalingLazyColumn items continuously

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

**Issue**

I'm still new to compose and I'm trying to show the user a list of timers that keep updating the UI every second. For Wear OS I have a ScalingLazyColumn (I assume it's similar to LazyColumn for regular phones) where I show various timers couting down. The issue I'm having is that I can show the items in the list, but the UI stops updating them after 2 or 3 seconds, whilst the source keeps getting modified in the background. As an addition, I want to show the timers that still have time remaining at the top and all other sorted by the time they were entered.

**Picture this**

Let's assume we're trying to cook a dish. In order to finish it we need require several timers. One for the bread in the oven, one for the patatoes that are cooking, etc.

So below you can see a class called Dish that has a property timers. These timers can be added and they will be updated. I just made this all up, it's just to show you what I've done (non working sample).

```
data class Dish(
    var name: String
) {
    //private val timers: MutableList<Timer>? = mutableListOf()
    private var timers: SnapshotStateList<Timer>? = mutableStateListOf()

    fun addTimer(name: String, startTimestamp: Long, duration: Long) {
        val newTimer = Timer(name, startTimestamp, duration)
        timers!!.add(newTimer)
    }

    fun getTimers(): SnapshotStateList<Timer> {
        return timers!!
    }

    fun getSortedTimers(): SnapshotStateList<Timer> {
        val mySortedFinishedTTimers: SnapshotStateList<Timer> = mutableStateListOf()
        val mySortedUnfinishedTimers: SnapshotStateList<Timer> = mutableStateListOf()

        return if (!timers.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            timers!!.asReversed().forEach {
                if (it.timeremaining <= 0)
                    mySortedFinishedTimers.add(it)
                else
                    mySortedUnfinishedTimers.add(it)
            }
            mySortedUnfinishedTimers.sortBy { it.timeRemaining }
            mySortedUnfinishedTimers.addAll(mySortedFinishedTimers)
            mySortedUnfinishedTimers
        } else
            mySortedUnfinishedTimers
    }

    fun updateTimers() {
        val currentTimeMs: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()

        for (timer: Timer in timers!!) {
            if (!timer.paused && !timer.finished) {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - (timer.startTimestamp + timer.pausedDuration) >= timer.duration) {
                    timer.timeRemaining = 0
                    timer.finished = true
                } else {
                    timer.timeRemaining = System.currentTimeMillis() - (timer.startTimestamp + timer.pausedDuration)
                }
            } else if (timer.paused) {
                // Do paused stuff (eg. increasing pausedDuration)
            }
        }
    }

}

data class Timer(
    var name: String,
    var startTimestamp: Long,
    var duration: Long,
    var endTimestamp: Long = 0L,
    var pausedDuration: Long = 0L,
    var timeRemaining: Long = 0L,
    var paused: Boolean = false,
    var finished: Boolean = false
) {

    init {
        endTimestamp = startTimestamp + duration
        timeRemaining = duration
    }

}
```

The App has a timer that calls the processUpdates() method every second, so it calculated how much time is remaining on the timers.

In my ViewModel I'm not only updating the timers, but after that I update various variables for compose. So in order to show the timers in the ScalingLazyColumn I tried 2 things:

1. in compose loop through the timers directly from the DishViewModel dish variable like so:
   `for (timer in dishViewModel.dish.getTimers()) {` or (preferably)
   `for (timer in dishViewModel.dish.getSortedTimers()) {`
2. In compose loop through the timers set in the DishViewModel variable dishTimers like so:
   `for (timer in dishViewModel.dishTimers) {`

DishViewModel:

```
var dish: Dish = Dish("Nasi goreng")
var dishTimers = SnapshotStateList<Timer>()
    private set

fun processUpdates() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        dish.updateTimers()
        if (dishIsUpdating)
            updateDishUI()
    }
}

fun updateDishUI() {
    dishTimers = dish.getSortedTimers()
    // or
    // keep dishTimers variables in tact and 
    // start updating existing timers and adding new ones here from dish.getTimers()
}
```

**Possible solutions**

At first my list of timers was a MutableList? instead of SnapshotStateList?, no difference. Since I try to sort the timers also, I stopped doing that hoping that could make a difference, no luck. I also updated the dish variable in the DishViewModel to `var dish: Dish by mutableStateOf(Dish())`, no difference.

Using the SnapshotStateList<>, throws me errors, because there is no serializer found for this class. Since I serialize my classes, this is also an issue. Using MutableList<> doesn't have this issue.

Currently all attempts are ending up the same way, compose only updates the UI for the first 2 or 3 seconds and then stops. Although I've read other articles about this, I haven't succeeded yet. Maybe I'm missing something, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Other compose updates are working just fine.

**Update**

After more reading and some trial and error, I returned to the basics with the classes and just changed a simple thing that solved it all.

So the timers variable was returned to:

`private val timers: MutableList<Timer>? = mutableListOf()`

And the only thing I changed was:

`var timeRemaining: Long = 0L`

to

`var timeremaining by mutableLongStateOf(0L)`

That seemed to do the trick. In the composable I iterate through the timers:

`for (timer in dishViewModel.dish.getSortedTimers()) {`

Only concern I have is that I also use these classes in a Kotlin Multiplatform project with iOS and a class variable or type mutableLongStateOf is probably not supported by iOS.

Comment: Testing with var dish: Dish by mutableStateOf(Dish()) gives me strange and unwanted behavior. Don't know why. Maybe some of the Dish methods or properties are not ok (not from the example I gave, but in my actual project (too big too share).